# Stuck solving a logarithmic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\log _{ 2 }{ 2x } =\log _{ 4 }{ 4x^{ 6 } } -\log _{ 2 }{ 2x } $$

Steps I took:

$$\frac { \log _{ 4 }{ 2x }  }{ \log _{ 4 }{ 2 }  } =\log _{ 4 }{ 4x^{ 6 } } -\frac { \log _{ 4 }{ 2x }  }{ \log _{ 4 }{ 2 }  } $$

$$2\log _{ 4 }{ 2x } +2\log _{ 4 }{ 2x } =\log _{ 4 }{ 4x^{ 6 } } $$

$$4\log _{ 4 }{ 2x } =\log _{ 4 }{ 4x^{ 6 } } $$

At this point I get stuck I don't think turning this into $\log _{ 4 }{ (2x)^{ 4 } } =\log _{ 4 }{ 4x^{ 6 } } $ is the right answer. It leads to: $16x^{ 4 }=4x^{ 6 }$ and this has what seem to be extraneous solutions.

Comment: X = 2 seems to work from the last equation as well as the original equation

Comment: Just plug and check all the solutions?

Comment: x can not be zero or neg as log0 and log(neg) are undefined.  So, no, so 5 of the six extranious solutions aren't actually solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\log_{2} 2x = \log_{4} 4x^{6} - \log_{2}2x \quad \text{iff} \quad \frac{\log 2x}{\log 2} = \frac{\log 4x^{6}}{\log 4} - \frac{\log 2x}{\log 2};\\
\frac{\log 2x}{\log 2} = \frac{\log 4x^{6}}{\log 4} - \frac{\log 2x}{\log 2} \quad \text{iff} \quad 2\log 2x = \log 4x^{6} - 2\log 2x;\\
2\log 2x = \log 4x^{6} - 2\log 2x \quad \text{iff} \quad
\log (2x)^{4} = \log 4x^{6};\\
\log (2x)^{4} = \log 4x^{6} \quad \text{iff} \quad x = 2.
$$

Comment: Since -2 and 0 cant be solution, 2 is the only solution.

Comment: @YunusSyed Thanks; intended to make it as a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Using: $\log_a b=\frac{\log a}{\log b}, \log ab=\log a + \log b, \log_a a=1$
$$\implies\log _{ 2 }2+\log _{ 2 }{ x } =\log _{ 4 }{ 4}+\log _{ 4 }{ x^{ 6 } } -\log _{ 2 }{ 2}-\log _{ 2 }{ x } $$
$$\implies1+\log _{ 2 }{ x } =6\frac{\log _{ 2 }{ x }}{\log_2 4} -\log _{ 2 }{ x } +1-1$$
$$\implies1+\log _{ 2 }{ x } =6\frac{\log _{ 2 }{ x }}{2}-\log _{ 2 }{ x } $$
$$\implies1+\log _{ 2 }{ x } =3{\log _{ 2 }{ x }}-\log _{ 2 }{ x } $$
$$\implies{\log _{ 2 }{ x }}=1 $$
$$\implies x=2^1$$